# Changing value in a list?

Tags: python, list

Following on from a previous question, I have the following code. For some reason, the value is not changed in the list, although the `currentlikes` has been incremented. The comments explain what I am attempting to do:

```
print("PRINT THE CURRENT FILM ROW", allfilms[3])
print("PRINT THE CURRENT LIKES", allfilms[3].split(",")[4])
currentlikes=allfilms[3].split(",")[4] #this retrieves the current likes from field
print(currentlikes)
currentlikes=+1 #this increments the current likes stored in the list
print(currentlikes)
allfilms[3].split(",")[4]=currentlikes #this attempts to change the value from 0 to 1 in the respective field
print(allfilms)#this should print the updated list with the incremented +1 in the Third Row, Fourth Field (0 to 1)
```

The output is as follows. It does, as mentioned, change the current likes, but when we print `allfilms` at the end, the relevant field has not been updated.

`PRINT THE CURRENT FILM ROW 3,Sci-Fi,Star Trek, PG, 0
PRINT THE CURRENT LIKES  0
0
1
['0,Genre, Title, Rating, Likes', '1,Sci-Fi,Out of the Silent Planet, PG, 0', '2,Sci-Fi,Solaris, PG,0', '3,Sci-Fi,Star Trek, PG, 0', '4,Sci-Fi,Cosmos, PG, 0', '5,Drama, The English Patient, 15, 0', '6,Drama, Benhur, PG, 0', '7,Drama, The Pursuit of Happiness, 12, 0', '8,Drama, The Thin Red Line, 18, 0', '9,Romance, When Harry met Sally, 12, 0', "10,Romance, You've got mail, 12, 0", '11,Romance, Last Tango in Paris, 18, 0', '12,Romance, Casablanca, 12, 0']`

Comment: `allfilms[3].split(",")` returns a new list and you are not storing this list anywhere

Comment: The return value of `allfilms[3].split(",")` has no lingering connection to `allfilms` or `allfilms[3]`; modifying it won't automatically modify `allfilms`.

Comment: Is **currentlikes=+1** a typo ?

Answer (score 1):

`allfilms[3].split(",")` splits the given string and returns a *new list* that has *no connection to the string*.

You will need to join the list and overwrite the string at `allfilms[3]`.

```
>>> x = '3,Sci-Fi,Star Trek, PG, 0';
>>> record = x.split(',')
>>> record[4] = 1
>>> x
'3,Sci-Fi,Star Trek, PG, 0'
>>> record
['3', 'Sci-Fi', 'Star Trek', ' PG', 1]
>>> x = ','.join(str(i) for i in record)
>>> x
'3,Sci-Fi,Star Trek, PG,1'
```

Comment: Would suggest `record[4] = int(record[4].strip()) + 1` as OP wants to increment the 'like' field.